# Building Array in forloop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a basic for loop which creates an array but am a little confused in how to structure it... this is an example of the array:

```
var list = [
{id: "135", data: [9,129,345, 687]},
{id: "239", data: [596,382,0,687,33467]}
];
```

Those are just example numbers but i need to make it in a for loop (because the numbers come from variables, but i've got no idea how i do it =/

I know how to make a 1 dimensional array with a for loop but not anything this complex..

Does any one have an example loop to show how its structured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Just understood what you meant.

This is a bit of pseudo to show how you would create an array like the one in question

```
var list = [];

for(var i = 0; i < objectcount; i++){

    // Here you need some way to get the ID for each should be dependant on 'i'
    var obj = {id: 10, data: []}; object
    for(var j = 0; j < datacount; j++){

        // You need some way to retrieve each data number, dependent on 'j'
        obj.data.push(somenumber) 
    }

    list.push(obj)
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Assuming that you want to create an array of all the data arrays inside each object try something like this:

```
var newarray = [];

// This will iterate through each object in the list array.
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

    // This will iterate though each value in the data array 
    // of the current list object
    for(var j = 0; j < list[i].data.length; j++){

        // Then you add that value to 'newarray'
        newarray.push(list[i].data[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: See my paste to here to better understand :
http://www.paste.to/MzYwOTQ3

The creation is based on boolean checks if an object exists in a given grid then 4 numbers are added to that id based on maths from variables.

Comment: You should update your question with that code so that everyone knows what I'm talking about when I answer it.

Comment: Should listobj be global set because i get listobj is not defined

Comment: @Dave No, in the pastebin I made the only interaction with listObj is within the scope of the inner if statement. If you try to interact without outside of that function (or before you create it) it will give listObj is note defined. `list` however should be declared globally. As I said before, you should add your original pastebin to the question so this can be answered within SO.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but to access the list object as shown you could

```
alert(list[0].id);
alert(list[0].data[0]);
```

and you would get 135 and 9 respectively.

Here's the for loops to see them all:

```
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    alert (list[i].id);
    for (j=0; j<list[i].data.length; j++) {
        alert (list[i].data[j]);
    }
}
```